# Networking buggy in 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Wifi keeps dropping security code and asking for authentication. will not connect now even when I re-edit the connection or enter manually in the pop up that continually occurs. Seems stuck in a loop. No luck re-booting several times.
Results:
     peter@peter-laptop:~$ lspci

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS300 Host Bridge (rev 02)
 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS300 AGP Bridge
 00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] OHCI USB Controller #1 (rev 01)
 00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] OHCI USB Controller #2 (rev 01)
 00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] EHCI USB Controller (rev      01)
 00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SMBus (rev 1a)
 00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Dual Channel Bus      Master PCI IDE Controller
 00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 434c
 00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP200 3COM 3C920B      Ethernet Controller
 00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP150 AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
 00:14.6 Modem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP AC'97 Modem (rev 01)
 01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV350/M10 [Mobility Radeon 9600 PRO Turbo]
 02:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev 80)
 02:02.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR5212/AR5213 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
 02:03.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
 02:04.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB-710/2/4 Cardbus Controller
 02:04.1 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Memory Stick Card Reader Controller
 02:04.2 SD Host controller: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Secure Digital Card Reader Controller
 02:04.3 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc:

peter@peter-laptop:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:b0:3a:19:54  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:900 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:900 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:66460 (66.4 KB)  TX bytes:66460 (66.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:f5:29:f1:38  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
peter@peter-laptop:~$ sudo iwconfig
[sudo] password for peter: 
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: could it be a side effect of having changed you file permission modes or ownership in your homedir ?

Comment: Can you please add to your post (1) the PCI and subsystem ID numbers and (2) the kernel driver in use for the wireless interface device? You should be able to see them using the `lspci` command in verbose/numeric mode e.g. `sudo lspci -vnn | awk '/\[0280\]/,/Kernel/ {print}'`

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar problem wich i solved creating a file called resolv.conf at folder etc. 
After that It starts connecting.

```
sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

The file contain the name servers:

nameserver 127.0.1.1